# Users Logged out after few minutes (Asp.NET Core 5 Identity)

Tags: asp.net-core, cookies, asp.net-identity

In my localhost user never logout even I click logout but when I publish my site to internet host users logged out after a few minutes

I am using identity 5 - login looks like this:

```
 var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(Input.Email, Input.Password, Input.RememberMe, lockoutOnFailure: false);
```

and in external login :

```
  var result = await _signInManager.ExternalLoginSignInAsync(info.LoginProvider, info.ProviderKey, isPersistent: true);
```

My startup is:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
        services.AddControllersWithViews();
        services.AddRazorPages();
          
        services.Configure<IdentityOptions>(options =>
        {
            options.Password.RequireDigit = true;
            options.Password.RequiredLength = 6;
            options.Password.RequireLowercase = false;
            options.Password.RequireUppercase = false;
            options.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
            
        });
}

// This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
       //some default code here 

        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseAuthorization();

      // here default route map
}
```

Comment: It would be understandable if you post your all AccountController code.I will check.

Comment: Do post a copy of the logout logic in the controller

Comment: Any luck with this? I'm having the exact issue you are having.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(opt =>
{
    opt.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(60);
    opt.LoginPath = "/Identity/Account/Login";
    opt.SlidingExpiration = true;
});
```

After 60 minutes of inactivity, the user will be directed to the login page